# Ingesting csv data into elastic search error: BulkIndexError: ('10 document(s) failed to index

Tags: python, elasticsearch, indexing

I am running Elasticsearch instance on Windows 10 and trying to ingest a sample csv data into it:

```
company_name id  homepage_url
coca-cola     1   www.coca-cola.com
microsoft     2   www.microsoft.com
...
google        10  www.google.com
```

I have an Elasticsearch service started.

Here is my Python code:

```
import csv
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost', 'port':9200}])
mappings = {
    'mappings': {
        'my-index' : {
            'properties' : {
                'company_name': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
                'id': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
                'homepage_url': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
        }
       }
     }
   }


  es.index(index="my-index", ignore=400, id = 1, body=mappings)

  with open('data.csv') as f: 
       reader = csv.DictReader(f)
       helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='my-index')
```

When I run it, I get this error in the last line:

```
 BulkIndexError: ('10 document(s) failed to index.',
```

Why am I getting it? What arguments am I not indicating in the last line (if that's an issue)?

**EDIT:** A full error message:

```
    BulkIndexError: ('10 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index': {'_index': 
'my-index', '_type': 'csv', '_id': '_UeXFXIBkMp4belsHQ93', 'status': 
400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting 
mapping update to [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 
1 type: [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '42'), 
('id', 'dab633e6-92bc-92a4-b749-21da835ad266'), ('homepage_url', 
'http://www.42.fr')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', '_type': 
'csv', '_id': '_keXFXIBkMp4belsHQ93', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 
'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping update to 
[my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 
csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '47'), ('id', 
'db4be793-725e-468e-abbd-c058078d67c6'), ('homepage_url', 
'http://47brand.com')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', '_type': 
'csv', '_id': '_0eXFXIBkMp4belsHQ93', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 
 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping update to 
 [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 
 csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '52'), ('id', 
 '861d168c-b703-47ed-8b23-1cc06c3a297d'), ('homepage_url', 
 'https://52inc.com/')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', '_type': 
 'csv', '_id': 'AEeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 
 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping update to 
  [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, 
  csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '55'), ('id', 
  '01eb53db-bcee-c57f-3ab1-54fb53f6de65'), ('homepage_url', 
  'http://www.fifty-five.com')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', 
  '_type': 'csv', '_id': 'AUeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 'status': 400, 'error': 
  {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping update 
   to [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: 
   [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '99'), 
   ('id', 'c1723121-d8a2-457c-1b81-25fc42e78d95'), 
    ('homepage_url', 'http://99app.com')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 
   'my-index', '_type': 'csv', '_id': 'AkeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 'status': 
    400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting 
    mapping update to [my-index] as the final mapping would have more 
    than 1 type: [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', 
    '111'), ('id', '0680987f-23cd-4fa5-850c-38326fffaa36'), 
    ('homepage_url', 'http://corporate.111.com.cn')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 
    'my-index', '_type': 'csv', '_id': 'A0eXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 
    'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 
    'Rejecting mapping update to [my-index] as the final mapping would 
     have more than 1 type: [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': 
     OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '121'), ('id', 'f937b68d-
     577b-4a77-8f6f-39d29fb220fd'), ('homepage_url', 
     'http://121corp.com')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', 
     '_type': 'csv', '_id': 'BEeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 'status': 400, 'error': 
     {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping 
     update to [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 
     type: [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '216'), 
     ('id', '11b04fed-bd66-7a84-32cd-3a8df0e36045'), 
     ('homepage_url', 'https://www.216.nl/')])}}, {'index': {'_index': 
     'my-index', '_type': 'csv', '_id': 'BUeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 
     'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 
     'Rejecting mapping update to [my-index] as the final mapping would 
      have more than 1 type: [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': 
      OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '237'), ('id', 'bd023349-
      36d4-4ec4-de8b-427dac4291f7'), ('homepage_url', 'http://237.io/')])}}, 
      {'index': {'_index': 'my-index', '_type': 'csv', '_id': 
      'BkeXFXIBkMp4belsHRB3', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 
      'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Rejecting mapping update to 
      [my-index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: 
      [_doc, csv]'}, 'data': OrderedDict([('ï»¿company_name', '366'), 
      ('id', 'ba116a57-c83c-0d99-0f71-dd0735fc19e7'), 
      ('homepage_url', 'http://www.366.fr/')])}}])
```

Comment: Please add the complete error log

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of the newer versions of ES, you're getting the error

> Rejecting mapping update to [my-index] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [_doc, csv]

which makes sense because `doc_types` are [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html).

Change the last part of your code to

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='my-index')       # <-- no `doc_type`
```

Comment: I still get thi smessage, after removing the doc_type.

Comment: You've got empty key-value pairs in your ordered dicts -- ('', '') is invalid. Filter out empty keys before you bulk-sync!

Comment: you are correct, because I cleared content of the csv, instead of deleting columns. But the error still remains. I updated the error.

Comment: Drop the index & resync then.

Comment: I dropped the index, and then I get "BulkIndexError: ('10 document(s) failed to index.'".